# How to change video created / modified date on Android

Tags: android, file, video-processing

I'm doing a video trimming thanks to [Mp4Composer](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android). Everything is fine except the output video metadata date is for today. But I want to have date of original file.

Is it possible to **set** this metadata for a video/mp4 file?

Comment: The Android `File` class has a `setLastModified` setting that can be set when creating a new file to storage. Try saving the **lastModifed** date of your input file and set same value to the edited new file. I don't think you're allowed to modify the `created` date using Android SDK.

Comment: I don't mean file metadata but video metadata